# gdb specific environment variables

Tags: gdb

I noticed that there are a couple of gdb specific environment variables introduced into the stack during debugging. Is there any way I could unset those environment variables alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that there are a couple of gdb specific environment variables introduced into the stack during debugging.

You must be using some kind of IDE, or a wrapper script, that does this. GDB itself doesn't modify environment, unless you ask it to with e.g. `set env` command.